# SQL Server Full Text Search to match contact name to prevent duplicates

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Using SQL Server Azure or 2017 with Full Text Search, I need to return possible matches on names.

Here's the simple scenario: an administrator is entering contact information for a new employee, first name, last name, address, etc.  I want to be able to search the Employee table for a possible match on the name(s) to see if this employee has already been entered in the database.

This might happen as an autosuggest type of feature, or simply display some similar results, like here in Stackoverflow, while the admin is entering the data.

I need to prevent duplicates!

If the admin enters "Bob", "Johnson", I want to be able to match on:

- Bob Johnson
- Rob Johnson
- Robert Johnson

This will give the administrator the option of seeing if this person has already been entered into the database and choose one of those choices.

Is it possible to do this type of match on words like "Bob" and include "Robert" in the results?  If so, what is necessary to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably a lookup table that associates names with certain other names would be the simplest way (there may be some examples of this already floating around, I haven't checked). But one thing you should note is that it is entirely possible for two different people to have the same given name and surname.

Comment: Yes, that is understood that there could be multiple persons with the same first and last name, but I could at least display a list of possible choices to the user for them to choose from, if one is the one they want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You need to change the `@per` parameter value to your requirement. It indicates how many letters out of the length of the first name should match for the result to return. I just set it to 50% for testing purposes.

The dynamic SQL piece inside the loop adds all the `CHARINDEX` result per letter of the first name in question, to all existing  first names.

Caveats:

Repeating letters will of course be misleading, like Bob will count 3 matches in Rob because there's 2 Bs in Bob.

I didn't consider 2 first names, like Bob Robert Johnson, etc so this will fail. You can improve on that however, but you get the idea.

The final SQL query gets the `LetterMatch` that is greater than or equal to the set value in `@per`.

```
DECLARE @name       varchar(MAX)    =   'Bobby Johnson' --sample name
DECLARE @first      varchar(50)     =   SUBSTRING(@name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @name))  --get the first part of the name before space
DECLARE @last       varchar(50)     =   SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name) + 1, LEN(@name) - LEN(@first) - 1) --get the last part of the name after space
DECLARE @walker     int             =   1   --for looping
DECLARE @per        float           =   LEN(@first) * 0.50  --declare percentage of how many letters out of the length of the first name should match. I just used 50% for testing
DECLARE @char       char    --for looping
DECLARE @sql        varchar(MAX)    --for dynamic SQL use
DECLARE @matcher    varchar(MAX)    =   ''  --for dynamic SQL use

WHILE @walker <> LEN(@first) + 1 BEGIN --loop through all the letters of the first name saved in @first variable
    SET @char = SUBSTRING(@first, @walker, 1) --save the current letter in the iteration
    SET @matcher = @matcher + IIF(@matcher = '', '', ' + ') + 'IIF(CHARINDEX(''' + @char + ''', FirstName) > 0, 1, 0)' --build the additional column to be added to the dynamic SQL
    SET @walker = @walker + 1 --move the loop
END


SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT FirstName, LastName, ' + @matcher + ' AS LetterMatch
                           FROM TestName
                           WHERE LastName LIKE '  + '''%' + @last + '%''' + ') AS src
            WHERE CAST(LetterMatch AS int) >= ROUND(' + CAST(@per AS varchar(50)) + ', 0)'
SELECT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: While this looks Ok, it doesn't look like it uses Full Text Search to do the matches, or am I wrong?  I was hoping FTS did this type of thing out-of-the-box, or at least something close.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention to the other tag.

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT * FROM tbl_Names
>   WHERE Name LIKE '% user defined text %';

using a text in between % % will search those text on any position in the data.

Comment: yes but will it return "Robert" if I enter "Bob" for the first name?  I don't think so.